# svnserve command not found

Tags: server, ssh, svn

I had my svn setup working for years, and now suddenly it has decided to not work. I am using svn+ssh. I can just ssh into the server fine, after that  I can run `type svnserve`which gives me`svnserve is /usr/local/bin/svnserve`, I can also do this from client as:

```
ssh -p 1234 user@myserver "sh -l -c 'type svnserve'"
```

and get the same response as above. However when I run

```
svn list -v svn+ssh://user@myserver/my_repo
```

it gives me `sh: svnserve: command not found` after the SSH authentication success. I can list repo fine if I do it directly on server without the ssh. Can anyone please help? Thanks

p.s. I am the only user who uses this svn server.

Comment: Is `user@myserver`'s login shell really `/bin/sh`? Where is `/usr/local/bin` added to their path when you log in interactively (via `/etc/environment` or somewhere else, such as `~/.profile`?)

Comment: For 'user@myserver', 'ps -p $$' output show 'sh', 'type sh' gives 'sh is /bin/sh'. Path is defined in '/etc/profile'. The svn server is on synology disk satation

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

1. Create svnwrapper.sh (`vi svnwrapper.sh`)

   #!/bin/sh

   #set the umask so files are group-writable
   umask 002

   #call the 'real' svnserve, also passing in the default repo location
   exec /usr/local/bin/svnserve "$@" -r /
2. save it in user dir
   e.g. `/var/services/homes/my_user`  - this is on synolgy NAS
3. `chmod 755 svnwrapper.sh`
4. `cd /usr/bin`
5. `ln -s /var/services/homes/my_user/svnwrapper.sh svnserve`
6. create .bashrc (`vi .bashrc`) in /var/services/homes/my_user and `chmod 755 .bashrc`
   content of .bashrc is

   #!/bin/sh

   export PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

Note the `exec /usr/local/bin/svnserve "$@" -r /` in svnwrapper, this will allow you to use full path in the repo on client, replace the last `/` with the path from where you want to start your repos.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was enough to run

```
ln -s /var/packages/SVN/target/bin/svnserve /usr/bin/svnserve
```

on the Synology.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this! <3
This saved our company SVN! :)

Looks like the combination of recent DSM and SVN updates must have screwed something up deep down. Tracing the SSH and SVN error messages via Terminal, it seems that the culprit is the svnserve binary that isn't found by the machine user that starts the SH process that then tries to run svnserve.

There is however a much more simple (and, granted, brutish) solution to the issue, without the need for any wrappers or scripts or BASH profiles: just create a globally available SymLink to the actual location of the svnserve binary file in its Synology packet path.

The svnserve in the Synology SVN packet is located here:
/var/packages/SVN/target/bin/svnserve

All I ultimately had to do was create a SymLink in the /usr/bin/ folder to that file, and now everything works again as intended.

So log in via SSH, then

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /var/packages/SVN/target/bin/svnserve svnserve
```

And that should do the trick. "Works here." :)

Without your instructions, we'd probably still be in a panic and looking for a solution, so thank you again for figuring this one out!